# How to switch a 2D texture in ArSceneView in google ar core at runtime

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

We all have used augmented face texture either on Instagram or Snapchat or any other application. I'm trying to develop a sample app where one can try on some ar objects on their faces. So far, I've been able to display that object on the face.

Then I'm displaying a list of items below ( on the screen ) so that user can switch the object to some other object ( similar to trying out new filters on instagram / snapchat ).

This is the default code for one object:

```
         Texture.builder()
               .setSource(this, R.drawable.fox_face_mesh_texture)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(texture -> faceMeshTexture1 = texture);

        ArSceneView sceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();
        sceneView.setCameraStreamRenderPriority(Renderable.RENDER_PRIORITY_FIRST);
        Scene scene = sceneView.getScene();
        scene.addOnUpdateListener(new Scene.OnUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
                if (faceMeshTexture1 == null)
                    return;

                Collection<AugmentedFace> faceList =
                        sceneView.getSession().getAllTrackables(AugmentedFace.class);

                for (AugmentedFace face : faceList) {
                    if (!faceNodeMap.containsKey(face)) {
                        AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = new AugmentedFaceNode(face);
                        faceNode.setParent(scene);
                        faceNode.setFaceMeshTexture(faceMeshTexture1);
                        faceNodeMap.put(face, faceNode);
                    }
                }

                Iterator<Map.Entry<AugmentedFace, AugmentedFaceNode>> iter = 
                    faceNodeMap.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry<AugmentedFace, AugmentedFaceNode> entry = iter.next();
                        AugmentedFace face = entry.getKey();
                        if (face.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.STOPPED) {
                            AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = entry.getValue();
                            faceNode.setParent(null);
                            iter.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
        });
```

What I've tried

In button onClick - I created a new Texture by doing `Texture.builder().setSource ...`

1) I tried to just write the for loop `for (AugmentedFace face : faceList) { ... }` But it did nothing.

2) I tried to include the whole contents of `onUpdate()` function. But that didn't work too.

3) Then I tried creating 2 textures and using a boolean variable to switch between those textures ( in the onUpdate method ) by reversing the boolean value ( on Button click ). It looks something like this:

```
         Texture.builder()
               .setSource(this, R.drawable.fox_face_mesh_texture)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(texture -> faceMeshTexture1 = texture);
        Texture.builder()
                .setSource(this, R.drawable.red_lipstick)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(texture -> faceMeshTexture2 = texture);



        ArSceneView sceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();

        sceneView.setCameraStreamRenderPriority(Renderable.RENDER_PRIORITY_FIRST);
        Scene scene = sceneView.getScene();
        scene.addOnUpdateListener(new Scene.OnUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
                if (faceMeshTexture1 == null || faceMeshTexture2 == null)
                    return;

                Collection<AugmentedFace> faceList =
                        sceneView.getSession().getAllTrackables(AugmentedFace.class);

                for (AugmentedFace face : faceList) {
                    if (!faceNodeMap.containsKey(face)) {
                        AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = new AugmentedFaceNode(face);
                        faceNode.setParent(scene);
                        if( !redOrFox ) {
                            faceNode.setFaceMeshTexture(faceMeshTexture1);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate: redorfox:" + redOrFox);
                        }
                        else {
                            faceNode.setFaceMeshTexture(faceMeshTexture2);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate: else redorfox:" + redOrFox);
                        }
                        faceNodeMap.put(face, faceNode);
                    }
                }

                Iterator<Map.Entry<AugmentedFace, AugmentedFaceNode>> iter = faceNodeMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<AugmentedFace, AugmentedFaceNode> entry = iter.next();
                    AugmentedFace face = entry.getKey();
                    if (face.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.STOPPED) {
                        AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = entry.getValue();
                        faceNode.setParent(null);
                        iter.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mBtnBlueLip.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            redOrFox = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: blue clicked");
        });

        mBtnRedLip.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            redOrFox = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: red clicked");
        });
```

But that didn't do anything too. At this point I'm clueless about what to do. There are barely any documentation regarding augmented faces and a few sample apps ( but in Kotlin ).
A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389203/changing-textures-of-object-in-ar-core-in-runtime) was found ( for 3D ) but with no answers.

edit:
Also after debugging, it seems like the onUpdate function is called only once. I don't understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this [kotlin app](https://github.com/Kristina-Simakova/arfaces) developed by [Kristina Simakova](https://github.com/Kristina-Simakova).

It seems like I was on the right track. What I missed was that the `face` object was already in the `faceList` array so it wasn't at all going in this if condition:

```
if (!faceNodeMap.containsKey(face)) { ... }
```

and since I had no else, nothing happened.

The solution would be have another boolean variable which checks whether the button was clicked or not!

```
Boolean isFox = false, changeModel = false;

...

scene.addOnUpdateListener(frameTime -> { 

...
  for (AugmentedFace face : faceList) {
    if (!faceNodeMap.containsKey(face)) {
        AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = new AugmentedFaceNode(face);
        faceNode.setParent(scene);
        faceNode.setFaceMeshTexture(faceMeshTexture1);
        faceNodeMap.put(face, faceNode);
    }
    else if (changeModel) {    // check whether we want to change texture
        if(isFox)
            faceNodeMap.get(face).setFaceMeshTexture(faceMeshTexture1);
        else
            faceNodeMap.get(face).setFaceMeshTexture(faceMeshTexture2);
    }
  }
changeModel = false; // after the for loop ends


...


    mBtnBlueLip.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        isFox = true;
        changeModel = true;
    });

    mBtnRedLip.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        changeModel = true;
        isFox = false;
    });
```

Kristina used a similar approach. Since I was testing the app and had only 2 textures, I used a boolean variable `isFox`. You can also maintain an array of your textures and keep only one `faceMeshTexture` variable which gets the value according to which button was clicked.